# Jenkins - To trigger pipeline only for event failed or successful for jenkins webhook trigger

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, regular-language

I want to trigger a pipeline for cases where it only triggers two cases when the event received is failed or successful using the Jenkins webhook trigger.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeDa5.png)

for eg: If I have an event log as JSON like the one below

```
{"involvedObject":{"kind":"HelmRelease","namespace":"flux-system","name":"my-release","uid":"1f86243d-bcd9-4e0a-b078-c9df8f9441ac","apiVersion":"helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1","resourceVersion":"1466894"},"severity":"info","timestamp":"2023-10-25T06:20:18Z","message":"Helm upgrade succeeded","reason":"info","metadata":{"revision":"6.5.2"},"reportingController":"helm-controller","reportingInstance":"helm-controller-578bd944df-m9sgx"}
```

I want this event to filter only messages using regexp `"Helm upgrade succeeded"` or `"Helm upgrade failed"`. If any other filter comes apart of this message it should not trigger my pipeline.

Any help over regexp for this would be great.
Tried ($failed|$success) , (failed|success).. dint work
**Note:** I am using the Jenkins webhook Trigger plugin for the above use case and using an optional filter under this plugin.

Comment: Try Generic Webhook Trigger plugin which allows you to perfom condition on the full webhook payload

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have modified my questions. Now please consider it

Comment: @Barelelbaz, I am using webhook trigger plugin itself and using optional filter which uses regexp but somehow not able to use correct regexp to achieve above scenerio.

Comment: Please provide more details about the value, the regex you tried, and what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Install the generic webhook trigger plugin and try this out

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        GenericTrigger(
               genericVariables: [
                       [key: 'payload', value: '$'],
                       [key: 'message', value: '$.message'],
               ],
               regexpFilterText: '$message',
               regexpFilterExpression: '(Helm upgrade succeeded)|(Helm upgrade failed)'
               causeString: 'Triggered by helm ', //give it any cause you want
               token: "<your-token>",
        )
    }
```